# where is the mistake in PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in line 3

Tags: php

```
**strong text**/****post-tag****/
function asr_tags() { 
$asrtags =  get_the_tags( get_the_ID());
foreach($asrtags as $tag){$string .= '<span class="post-tag"><a class="p-tag" href="'. get_tag_link($tag->term_id) .'">'. $tag->name . '</a></span>' . "\n";
} 
return $string;
} 
add_shortcode('asrtags' , 'asr_tags' );

/*****post-tag*****/
```

Answer (score 1):

[`get_the_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tags/) returns an array or `false` on failure. (It appears it may also return a `WP_Error` object under certain circumstances.)

It also **requires** a parameter: the post ID. You're not passing that, so you're not going to get the array your code expects.

**Edit**

You can't just call `get_the_tags()` -- that'll just get you a value of `false`. You **need** to provide a post ID.

This *might* work: replace

```
$asrtags =  get_the_tags();
```

with

```
$asrtags =  get_the_tags( get_the_ID() );
```

...but note that this will *only* work if you're in The Loop.

Comment: but this code still working.

Comment: please give me the correct code here

Comment: now its ok bro see the code                                                                    /****post-tag****/
function asr_tags() { 
$asr_tags =  get_the_tags();
foreach($asrtags as $tag){$string .= '<span class="post-tag"><a class="p-tag" href="'. get_tag_link($tag->term_id) .'">'. $tag->name . '</a></span>' . "\n";
} 
return $string;
} 
add_shortcode('asrtags' , 'asr_tags' );

/*****post-tag*****/

Comment: If you read [the documentation for `get_the_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tags/), you'll see that it **requires** a post ID. You can't just call `get_the_tags()`; you'll get `false` if you do that. To get an array of tags, you **need** to provide a post ID. See my edits.

Comment: again show error log  problem in this line ```  foreach($asrtags as $tag){$string .= '<span class="post-tag"><a class="p-tag" href="'. get_tag_link($tag->term_id) .'">'. $tag->name . '</a></span>' . "\n";
} ```

Comment: Please [edit the original question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/344525/edit) to reflect your updated code.

Comment: bro i dont understand

Comment: If you're using this line: `get_the_tags();` in your code, **that's your problem**. You *need* to pass `get_the_tags()` a post ID, otherwise *it won't work* and you'll run into the problem you're having. If you've added a post ID parameter to your code, please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/344525/edit) to show the updates.

Comment: i use the code  get_the_tags( get_the_ID() ); but same problem

Comment: but problem show in the code foreach($asrtags as $tag){$string .= '<span class="post-tag"><a class="p-tag" href="'. get_tag_link($tag->term_id) .'">'. $tag->name . '</a></span>' . "\n";
} 
return $string;
}

Comment: The foreach loop will fail if there are no tags as `$asrtags` will not contain an array. So, wrap the `foreach` loop in `if ( is_array( $asrtags )) { ... }`